# Palindrome comparison doesn't detect some cases

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, palindrome

I want to print True if the word/line is a palindrome.
The code reads the text from the text file (using sys.argv[1]).
I don't understand why it's only checks the first line.

text file:

```
racecar
AddE
HmllpH
Was it a car or a cat I saw
Hannah
T can arise in context where language is played wit
Able was I ere I saw Elba
Doc note I dissent A fast never prevents a fatness I diet on cod
```

code:

```
import sys
filename = sys.argv[1]

with open(filename, "r") as f:
    text = f.readline().strip().lower()

    while text:
        palindrome = True
        i = 0
        while i < len(text) / 2:
            if text[i] != text[len(text) - 1 - i]:
                palindrome = False
            i += 1
        if palindrome:
            print(True)
        text = f.readline().strip()
```

output:

```
True
```

Comment: Only the first line is a palindrome. Either way you can use `text == text[::-1]` to check if palindrome

Comment: Not sure if it has anything to do with this, but you can just loop `for text in f:` (and strip and lower in the loop)

Comment: Also, your code seems to work fine, but in the `False` case you never `print`, and all but the first are false as you never `lower` those.

Answer (score 3):

1. Why only the first line printed?

Only the first line is a case-sensitive palindrome.

2. Code Fix:

Some explanation on what you see:

2.1. The loop `for text in map(str.strip, f)`, means that we are going over file `f` lines and apply the `str.strip()` method on each of them.

2.2. `text.upper()` to convert text to unified upper case, for common comparison.

2.3. `text_upper[::-1]` to reverse text: The strange `[::-1]` index notation, means that we are going on all elements backward one step (therefore the -1).

```
import sys
filename = 'outfile.txt'

with open(filename, "r") as f:
    for text in map(str.strip, f):
        text_upper = text.upper()
        if text_upper == text_upper[::-1]:
            print(f'{text} is palindrom!')
```

Comment: Once we're at it, you might also change the loop to `for text in map(str.strip, f):`

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to replace the last line with `text = f.readline().strip().lower()`? In that case, you don't even need the `text_upper` variable.

Answer (score 0):

It does check all lines, but only the first case returns True because the other lines don't have `.lower()`. You would have to change the last line to `text = f.readline().strip().lower()`.